# Draggable and Editable title menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a HTML user interface that allow my users to drag or sort the menu's or utilities by what they want, similar to an Android or iOS HOME screen. How can I save the menu positions?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#items").sortable({
    placeholder: "highlight",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
    }
  });
  $("#items").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
.list {
  background-color: #478BFF;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

#items .ui-selected {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#items {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#items li {
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
}

.highlight {
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 45px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:520px">
  <ul id="items">
    <li class="list">1</li>
    <li class="list">2</li>
    <li class="list">3</li>
    <li class="list">4</li>
    <li class="list">5</li>
    <li class="list">6</li>
    <li class="list">7</li>
    <li class="list">8</li>
    <li class="list">9</li>
    <li class="list">10</li>
    <li class="list">11</li>
    <li class="list">12</li>
    <li class="list">13</li>
    <li class="list">14</li>
    <li class="list">15</li>
    <li class="list">16</li>
    <li class="list">17</li>
    <li class="list">18</li>
    <li class="list">19</li>
    <li class="list">20</li>
    <li class="list">21</li>
    <li class="list">22</li>
    <li class="list">23</li>
    <li class="list">24</li>
    <li class="list">25</li>
    <li class="list">26</li>
    <li class="list">27</li>
    <li class="list">28</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="info" style="font-family:Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:20px;"></div>
```

Comment: Help us help you and post what you have tried, what the specs are (like what programming language are you using, what's the database type etc.)

Comment: Build an array from the `.list` element's order when `stop` fires then save that array wherever you require, localStorage, cookie, AJAX to database etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `.map()` will get the current positions of each item:

```js
function save() {
  let positions = $.map(
    $('#items li'), 
    function(i){
      return parseInt($(i).text())
    });
  console.log(positions);
}

save();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:520px">
  <ul id="items">
      <li class="list">1</li>
      <li class="list">2</li>
      <li class="list">3</li>
      <li class="list">4</li>
      <li class="list">5</li>
      <li class="list">6</li>
      <li class="list">7</li>
      <li class="list">8</li>
      <li class="list">9</li>
      <li class="list">10</li>
      <li class="list">11</li>
      <li class="list">12</li>
      <li class="list">13</li>
      <li class="list">14</li>
      <li class="list">15</li>
      <li class="list">16</li>
      <li class="list">17</li>
      <li class="list">18</li>
      <li class="list">19</li>
      <li class="list">20</li>
      <li class="list">21</li>
      <li class="list">22</li>
      <li class="list">23</li>
      <li class="list">24</li>
      <li class="list">25</li>
      <li class="list">26</li>
      <li class="list">27</li>
      <li class="list">28</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Of course, instead of running it when page loads, you'll need to bind it on click of a button. And you should also rename it, so its name does not collide with some other function named by someone with as little imagination as yours truly.

---

**Side note:** Whenever you come across the need to give all children of a parent the same class, consider removing the class from each item and using the parent to style them. In your example:

```
<ul id="items">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

You can style the `<li>`s with `#items>li{ ... }` instead of `#items .list{ ... }`

Comment: @KaoriYui, I've added a side note, you might find it useful. Happy coding!